# glDrawArrays: Erasing the buffer between calls?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer

I have two VBOs, assigned to names 1 and 2. Only 2 is being drawn. However, if I comment out VBO 2, VBO 1 is drawn with no problem. Here's the relevant code.

```
                for m in shader._models:
                    try:
                        # Set the model's transform matrix uniform
                        vbo, mode = m.render_data
                        glUniformMatrix4fv(
                            shader.uniforms['model'][0],
                            1,
                            GL_FALSE,
                            np.array(m.model_matrix))
                        vbo.bind()  # Binds the VBO.
                        glDrawArrays(mode, 0, len(vbo))
                    finally:
                        vbo.unbind() # Unbinds it.
```

glGetting `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` in the loop gives me alternating 1 and 2s, so the buffers are binding correctly. The second object is smaller and positioned in a different location, so they aren't hiding each other.

The only explanation I can think of is glDrawArrays clears the whole buffer every time it draws? What the heck?

Comment: glDrawArrays does not clear the buffer, the problem is in your own code. Unbinding is an OpenGL design anti-pattern that should never be necessary if you write code the way the API is designed to be used, but unfortunately a lot of tutorials teach it. Also unfortunately, you have this abstracted so we don't actually know what's happening in your vbo.unbind call, but that's the first place I would look for problems.

Comment: To be more specific, binding object 0 does not actually unbind. Instead it changes the way the API works, or selects a default object. Texture 0 is a valid texture and binding it reverts to OpenGL 1.0 behaviour. VBO 0 reverts OpenGL to drawing from client side (system memory) arrays. VAO 0 reverts vertex specification to global state. And so on. So binding object 0 is not only not doing what you want, it is almost certainly having unintended side-effects that are masking other problems.

Comment: Thanks Maximus. Your comment didn't say much but it did answer my question and allowed me to find the bug. I was using the same VAO for both VBOs -- does each VBO need its own VAO, or was I just doing it wrong?

Additionally, do I need to unbind before exiting the program, or will OpenGL free the space for me?

Comment: Yes, you need a vertex array for every model you use. Those aren't storage, they couple the different parts of one single object together (normals, vertices, etc.), so instead of binding 8 vbos everytime you need to draw something, you can just bind one vao. Unbinding stuff doesn't delete it, nor does it mark it for deletion. You need to call `glDelete...` for everything you used.

Comment: When I learned VAOs several years ago, I read that it on drivers at the time, it didn't make much difference whether you switched between several VAOs, or repeatedly reconfigured the same VAO to point to different VAOs. It may have changed by now, or it may not have.